# Getting error while trying to load data in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to load data using the below code:

```
LOAD DATA  INFILE 'D:/TC/VKCSV/2015011500.f000' INTO TABLE raster_cell_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (cell_id,id,issue_date,valid_date,dew_point_temperature,RH,temperature,U,V);
```

But I am getting the below error:

```
Error Code: 29. File 'D:\TC\VKCSV\2015011500.f000' not found (Errcode: 2)
```

But file is located at at the given location.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing we are trying to access a file on the *client* host, and not on the MySQL Server host. In that case, we'd do:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
          ^^^^^
```

The `LOCAL` keyword tells MySQL that it's reading a file from the local client machine.  Without that keyword, we're telling the MySQL Server that the file is on the server machine.